# Find command cannot find file in subfolder if matching file exists on upper level

Tags: unix, find

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxxx 2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 21 12:19:18 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ mkdir test

$ cd test

$ mkdir logs

$ touch logs/log.2017-08-01

$ touch log.2017-08-04

$ ls -lAR
.:
total 4
-rw-rw---- 1 icestation_uat athapps    0 Aug  4 21:00 log.2017-08-04
drwxrwx--- 2 icestation_uat athapps 4096 Aug  4 21:00 logs

./logs:
total 0
-rw-rw---- 1 icestation_uat athapps 0 Aug  4 21:00 log.2017-08-01

$ find ./logs/ -name log.2017-08-??

$ find -D search ./logs/ -name log.2017-08-??
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 0, prev_depth=-2147483648 fts_path=`./logs/', fts_accpath=`./logs/'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=0 fts_path=`./logs/log.2017-08-01', fts_accpath=`log.2017-08-01'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level= 0, prev_depth=1 fts_path=`./logs/', fts_accpath=`./logs/'

$ find -D search ./logs/ -name log.2017-08-01
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 0, prev_depth=-2147483648 fts_path=`./logs/', fts_accpath=`./logs/'
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_NSOK, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=0 fts_path=`./logs/log.2017-08-01', fts_accpath=`log.2017-08-01'
./logs/log.2017-08-01
consider_visiting: fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level= 0, prev_depth=1 fts_path=`./logs/', fts_accpath=`./logs/'

$ rm log.2017-08-04

$ find ./logs/ -name log.2017-08-??
./logs/log.2017-08-01
```

Really do not understand, why find does not return anything on first call and works as expected after one file is removed.

**Note, if you will try to reproduce then two things matter**

1. Top level file should have today date in its name (i.e. I'm testing on 4-Aug-2017)
2. Mask passed to find command should match both: top level file and nested one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is missing quotes.  The following finds nothing:

```
$ find ./logs/ -name log.2017-08-??
```

But, the following finds the file that you want:

```
$ find ./logs/ -name 'log.2017-08-??'
./logs/log.2017-08-01
```

#### Explanation

The shell does *pathname expansion* before passing the command's arguments to find.  Observe:

```
$ echo find ./logs/ -name log.2017-08-??
find ./logs/ -name log.2017-08-04
```

The shell sees wildcards in the expression `log.2017-08-??` and looks for files that match that *glob*.  The shell finds `log.2017-08-04` and substitutes that in *before* the arguments are passed to `find`.  Since there is no file in the `/logs` directory that matches `log.2017-08-04`, `find` will return nothing.

The shell only does *pathname expansion* on unquoted expressions.  That is why this issue disappears when the expression is quoted.

Comment: Is there way to disable expansion for given script?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov You can accomplish that with `GLOBIGNORE='*'`.   It will serve you better in the long run, though, to learn to use quotes where needed.